# Python - Discord.py - wait_for() unexpected keyword argument error when trying to receive response from user via DM

Tags: python, discord.py

I am attempting to set up a bot feature that sends a DM asking the user to type in !Agree as a message. When they do this, they will then be assigned a higher permission role ("@approved).

I am using the code that was posted by Patrick on the link below:

[Creating Rule agreement when someone join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51882207/creating-rule-agreement-when-someone-join)

The DM's are being sent as expected (see below)

[image: dm]

but I am receiving an error :

```
msg = await client.wait_for("message", channel=dm.channel, author=member, check=check)
TypeError: wait_for() got an unexpected keyword argument 'channel'
```

I have tried removing the channel parameter as I was unsure if this was still needed, but the error remains the same, expect it will say unexpected keyword argument 'author'.

I have checked the documentation and I am unsure as to why this error is being presented.

The code I am using is below:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print("A member just joined and his name is" + member.name)
    approved = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="approved")
    
    Rules = "1. Do not DM the Owner or any other staff unless they have DMed you first! \n 2. Be kind, \n 3. Use common sense, \n 4. No swearing, \n 5. No racism or bullying, \n 6. No advertising, \n 7. Do not chat in #music Text or Voice channels, \n 8. Do not spam #applications if your application is accepted or denied! This is only to be used for submitting and staff members replying to the application. \n 9. Do not use or abuse bot commands you should not be using! \n 10. Do not @ any staff members unless it is an emergency.  "

    # DM user with rules
    await member.send("Hello {0.mention}, welcome to {0.guild.name}".format(member))
    await member.send(Rules)
    dm = await member.send("Type !agree to agree")

    # get response
    check = lambda s: s.lower().startswith("!agree")
    msg = await client.wait_for("message", channel=dm.channel, author=member, check=check)

    await client.add_roles(member, approved)
```

Thanks to anyone who is able to provide assistance or solve this issue.

Comment: The [documentation for discord.py@1.4.0a](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for) shows the only parameters for `wait_for` to be event, check, and timeout. It seems if you remove both the channel and author parameters, you'll no longer receive these errors.

Comment: @gallen thanks for this. I noticed i get a new error ```attributeerror: 'message' object has no attribute 'lower' ``` when i enter !agree into the dm with the bot. Any ideas on why I am receiving this error? Thanks

Comment: You're calling the `.lower()` method on a discord.py `message` object, when you mean to be calling it on a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what happens when you copy the code without examining the structure. That code is expired and is of the old library. Things have been changed a lot since the new update.

I have made the corrections and it should work.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print("A member just joined and his name is" + member.name)
    approved = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="approved")
    
    Rules = " YOUR RULES"

    # DM user with rules
    await member.send("Hello {0.mention}, welcome to {0.guild.name}".format(member))
    await member.send(Rules)
    dm = await member.send("Type !agree to agree")

    #VERIFY DM Channel == Message Channel
    def check(message):
        return message.channel == dm.channel
    #Since the Library has changed, This is the correct FORM.
    msg = await client.wait_for('message',check = check)
    #Also, For adding the roles, You should use this format. The Client one is old and not working anymore.
    await member.add_roles(approved)
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I will ensure I am checking the correct documentation in future to try and fix future issues I may have.